# Trying to connect to database, getting error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I am new to oracle, I just installed oracle when I am trying to connect to the database I got this error.ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: How did you specify the database name?

Comment: If you run "lsnrctl status" on the server, it will tell you what instances are available to connect to.

Comment: @kfinity -  ora-12154 means the client couldn't even complete the request. The status of the listener and what it supports is totally irrelevent to this error.  ora-12154 is like not being able to find a telephone number in the telephone book.  If you can't find the number you can't even place the call, so it makes no difference what is going on at the switchboard (listener).

Comment: Unfortunately you chose to use a screen shot that did not include your actual 'sqlplus' command.  Fortunately, if you were to google 'ora-12154' you'd get _lots" of hits.  My favorite is here:  https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/

Answer (score 1):

To connect onn Oracle DB you should configure the file `tnsnames.ora` wich define DNS to your oracle server.

After configure file, you can test your connection with `tnsping DNS_NAMED_SERVER`

if you never heard about tns names, you can read more on Oracle Docs https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260